# Querying data based on 3rd level relationship in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, python-datamodel

I have the following relationships set up:

```
A HABTM B
B belongsTo C
C hasMany B
```

Now, for a given A, I need all C with the B's attached. I can write the SQL queries, but what's the proper CakePHP way? What method do I call on which model, and with which parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd go with Aziz' answer and simply process the data as it comes in. If you need C to be your primary model though, you'll have to do a little workaround. Cake is not terrifically good with conditions on related models yet, especially on removed 3rd cousins kind of queries. It usually only does actual JOIN queries on belongsTo or hasMany relations; not on HABTM relations though, those it gets in separate queries. That means you can't include conditions on related HABTM models.

Your best bet then might be something like this:

```
// get related records as usual with the condition on A, limit to as little data as necessary
$ids = $this->A->find('first', array(
    'conditions' => array('A.id' => 'something'), 
    'recursive'  => 2,
    'fields'     => array('A.id'),
    'contain'    => array('B.id', 'B.c_id', 'B.C.id') // not quite sure if B.C.id works, maybe go with B.C instead
));

// find Cs, using the ids we got before as the condition
$Cs = $this->C->find('all', array(
    'conditions' => array('C.id' => Set::extract('/B/C/id', $ids)),
    'recursive   => 1
);
```

Note that this produces quite a bunch of queries, so it's not really an optimal solution. Writing your own SQL might actually  be the cleanest way.

EDIT:

Alternatively, you could [re-bind your associations on the fly](http://book.cakephp.org/view/86/Creating-and-Destroying-Associations-on-the-Fly) to make them hasMany/belongsTo relationships, most likely using the join table/model of A and B. That might enable you to use conditions on related models more easily, but it's still tricky to fetch Cs when the condition is on A.

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->A->find(
   'first', 
   array('conditions'=>array('id'=>'someword'), 
   'recursive'=>2)
);
```

like this?

Comment: No, that puts the C under each B under the A. I need C first, with a list of B, with B has A as condition.

Comment: why find 'first'?? Shouldn't it be find 'all' as for a given A, all C's with B's attached are required.

Comment: @Adit: This finds *one* (the *first*) A and *all* the attached Bs and Cs.

Comment: $this->A->B->C->find('...
and it will collect models in relative of C

Comment: @Aziz: `$this->A->B->C` is identical to `$this->C` and won't help with conditions on `A`.

Answer (score 0):

this might work

```
$this->C->find('all',
array('conditions'=>array('id'=>'someword','B.aid'=>$a.id)));
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd think of "Containable" behaviour (http://book.cakephp.org/view/474/Containable)... gives a lot control on finding related data.